# How to get tableName , columnName ,constraintsType and cascade type in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need list of  tableName , columnName ,constraintsType and cascade type in sql server 2008 so i tried below query but cascade type is null

```
SELECT TB.name AS "TableName",CL.name AS 
"ColumnName",KC.type,FK.delete_referential_action,FK.update_referential_action  
FROM SYS.key_constraints KC JOIN SYS.tables TB ON   
KC.parent_object_id=TB.object_id JOIN SYS.columns CL ON  
KC.parent_object_id=CL.object_id LEFT JOIN SYS.foreign_keys FK ON FK.name = KC.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
o1.name AS FK_table,
c1.name AS FK_column,
fk.name AS FK_name,
fk.type as FK_TYPE,
pk.name AS PK_name,
pk.type as PK_TYPE,
fk.delete_referential_action_desc AS Delete_Action,
fk.update_referential_action_desc AS Update_Action
FROM sys.objects o1
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
    ON o1.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
    ON fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
    AND fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints pk
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = pk.parent_object_id
    AND fk.key_index_id = pk.unique_index_id
ORDER BY o1.name, fkc.constraint_column_id
```

I didn't try out your query as I don't a sql server in front of me but I believe you are missing a DMV and that is why your left join is returning nulls.